# Android: How to get image from remote server

Tags: php, android, json, wamp

I am developing an Android app that should get an image from remote server. Am using WAMP as my server and PHP as programming language. I know how to get text data using JSON.

Am not using blob to store image.
Images have stored in a folder on server. Url of image is stored in db table.

I tried the following snippet, I got this from net but it is not giving any error and also it is not displaying image

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/sareesProject/returnSareeTypeImageUrls.php");
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
entity = response.getEntity();
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
{
    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    if(entity != null)
    {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        JSONObject  jsonObj = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
        String base64Image = jsonObj.getString("pprs");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), base64Image, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        byte[] rawImage = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawImage, 0, rawImage.length);
    }
}
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

The following is my php code

```
 <?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("con error");
    mysql_select_db("sareesdb") or die("db select eror");
    $query = mysql_query("select * from noofpiecesinatype");
    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $response = $row['imageUrl'];
    }
    $response = base64_encode($response);
    echo '{"pprs":'.json_encode($response).'}';
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

I checked my php code with html(with out encoding $response value) am getting image there, but not in Android.

Comment: check this.. it will help you..http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Answer (score 2):

I am not good with Php, but if you return the file url via a JSON reponse you can use the following code for downloading the file.

```
int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://url of your file");
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
```

## Edit ##
After the Image is downloaded you can create a Bitmap from the Image Path/InputStream and assign it to the Image View like this

```
 BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
```

[Original source](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/)

Comment: Thank you for giving reply...... I think this code can be used to store the image on sd card. I don't want to store it, i need to set the image to ImageView list  ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Comment: Then you can create a Bitmap from the Inputstream and assign it to the listView

Comment: k. InputStream instream = entity.getContent(); at this stage i have InputStream. Could you tell me how to create a Bitmapt from this input stream. I also tried this bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawImage, 0, rawImage.length);

Comment: I tried with bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream); but it is returning null...............

Comment: Is the file is downloading?if yes have you tried saving it to /sdcard?

Comment: am not sure about downloading........ I successfully got image url stored in db.. BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream); this is also giving null.

Comment: That is because the inputStream is returning null,check if the file exists in the Server and check that you have set Permission for Internet in the Manifest As well as Read Permission in the server also

Comment: do one thing convert your image into byte array after that convert into string using base 64 and send to php server using json.In php decode json store string into mysql after that you will get response from server decode json and convert image string into byte array  using base decode and show it.

Comment: i want to post my code but it is not allowing me to post how can i post..............

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/sareesProject/returnSareeTypeImageUrls.php");
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            if(entity != null)
            {
                instream = entity.getContent();
                JSONObject  jsonObj = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
                bitmapPath = jsonObj.getString("pprs");
            }
        }
         try {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "http://10.0.2.2/sareesProject/"+bitmapPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/sareesProject/"+bitmapPath);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                bmp  = myBitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        if(bmp == null)
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);

        imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    //new HomePage().show("in con");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //show(line);
            //new HomePage().show("in while");
            //new HomePage().show("l="+line);
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       //Toast.makeText(, text, duration)
    } finally {
        try {
            if(reader != null)
            {
                try{reader.close();}
                catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}//end of convertStreamToString
```

The following is my php code

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("con error");
mysql_select_db("sareesdb") or die("db select eror");
$query = mysql_query("select * from noofpiecesinatype");
$response = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$response[] = $row['imageUrl'];
}
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

//--------------------
Fnally i got it.............

First of all my server file returns the following
{"pprs":"upload/22.png"}
from this i extracted upload/22.png using JSON
Now bitmapPath contains upload/22.png

Thank you very much to insomniac giving suggestions.............

If it is helpful to any one vote for me..............

Comment: Good example. If we want to display images in list view using above example can we do that ?